# Is there any view among academicians that an undergraduate degree is just a means to get to graduate school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

**Is there any view among academicians that an undergraduate degree is just a means to get to graduate school? Does it really matter that much where you finish your bachelor’s degree?**

College applicants don’t just choose their schools based on academic reputation and excellence. Financial consideration is perhaps the biggest factor in picking the right school, especially when one avoids serious debts. Sometimes, this factor leaves a student no other choice but to enroll in a lower-tier and non-ranking school. But this shouldn't discourage them from pursuing graduate studies, even when statistics show that most prestigious universities prefer applicants from an Ivy League school.

Comment: There's a lot of uncited assertions here which may or may not agree with conventional wisdom. In contrast and in my experience, lots of kids choose there undergraduate institution with an eye to future graduate admissions, not just in the Ivies in the US. On top of that, lots of industries like to hire top-tier university undergrads, so it's not just graduate school that cares where you got your undergraduate degree.

Comment: Again this is a US-centric view of the world. There are excellent universities in many countries in Europe for undergraduate studies without tuition fees.

Answer (score 12):

I must be understanding your question wrongly, but the way it is phrased it seems to ask whether academicians see the purpose of an undergraduate education only in terms of a student's ability to get into graduate school.

This is of course patently wrong, and I would imagine the number of my colleagues who see it that way to be very small: the vast majority of students get their undergraduate degrees not because they want to get into graduate school, but to obtain the necessary knowledge and qualification to enter the workforce with a Bachelor degree. For almost all students, graduate school is not a consideration, and professors of course know this very well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking whether *any* academicians see the undergraduate degree as valuable only as a way to get into grad school, there are probably some (and if "academicians" includes undergraduate students, the number goes up). It would be a distinctly rare opinion amongst faculty.

As to whether or not the institution "really matters", it would depends on the student (some students need lots of help) and the area of specialization (don't go to an arts-focused school to learn theoretical physics). In addition, undergraduates (in the US) who enter a university thinking they know what they will major in very often change their minds.

I think that the correct way to understand the undergraduate degree is that it is basic intellectual training for life, where you learn how to reason and argue, and essentially learn how to learn. You do that by gaining some techical competence in a particular area; and then if you want to go on for a technically-focused masters in accounting or fisheries, you will be prepared.

Comment: Learning how to learn:  absolutely. Plus the practical skills needed to learn more complex things efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any view among academicians that an undergraduate degree is just a means to get to graduate school?

The answer might be country-dependent, and from an Italian perspective the answer is: yes, absolutely.

The reasons are the following (the reasons behind these reasons are somewhat more complex and depend on the relatively recent introduction of the division undergraduate/graduate education in Italy):

1. If you want to pursue a career in academia, you need a PhD, and to apply for a PhD you *must* have a Master's degree.
2. If you want to pursue a career in industry, an undergraduate degree is not considered competitive with respect to a graduate one (in many industries here, applicants with an undergraduate degree are simply discarded).

So, here in Italy, the students who drop out of university just after their bachelor degree are typically those who: i) can't afford other two more years of university because of economical problems; ii) graduated with too low grades to enroll to a Master's program; and iii) have had enough of studying.

Given the above, most if not all of the Italian academics consider undergraduate education just an intermediate step toward graduate education.

Comment: That is all true, but in my experience in graduate studies it still matters *how* you got your bachelor: grades, acquired knowledge and quality of coursework attended. Solid foundations are invaluable in your future career; it is not just a checkbox to tick.